# Multiple Forked Processes Infinite Loop

Tags: c++, parallel-processing, fork

I'm not exactly sure how to describe this problem, I'm pretty sure it's not exactly an infinite loop (though it keeps running without exiting) because it seems like the program doesn't ever even start execution (I put a cout << "hello" right at the beginning of my main function and it doesn't get sent to the output). This is the part of the code that's screwing things up (when I comment this part out the program runs fine). This is my first time using the fork() command, so I might be missing something obvious:

```
for (int p = 0; p < processes; p++)
{
    if ((pids[p] = fork()) == 0)
    {
        for(int v = p * (360/processes); p < (360/processes) * (p + 1); p++)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < 360; i+=5)
            {
                match temp_match;
                float dissimilarity = 0;
                //calculate dissimilarity
                for (int j = 0; j < size; j++)
                {
                    dissimilarity += fabs(test_vector[j] - (search_set[v].vect)[(i + j) % 360]);
                }
                temp_match.x = search_set[v].x;
                temp_match.y = search_set[v].y;
                temp_match.offset = i;
                temp_match.dissimilarity = dissimilarity;
                result.push_back(temp_match);
            }
            //only keep keep the few with the smallest dissimilarity
            std::sort(result.begin(), result.end(), sort_function);
            result.resize(matches); 
        }
        for(int i = p * matches; i < (p + 1) * matches; i++)
        {
            *(shm + i * 4) = result[i].x;
            *(shm + i * 4 + 1) = result[i].y;
            *(shm + i * 4 + 2) = result[i].offset;
            *(shm + i * 4 + 3) = result[i].dissimilarity;
        }
        exit(0);
    }
    else if (pids[p] < -1)
    {
        cout << "uh oh";
        exit(1);
    }
    else
    {
        waitpid(pids[p], NULL, 0);
    }
}
```

So I guess I have two questions, am I using all the forking stuff right, and what could cause my program to compile but then not even begin execution when I run it?

Comment: So.. processes is *how big* ? (and do try and remember each *child* process is in that for-loop as well, so the parent will fork `processes` children, the first child will fork `processes-1`, its first child and the parents second child will fork `processes-2`, etc etc. See where this is going?)

Comment: Two problems, one huge. First off, you aren't setting `matches`. What is `matches` supposed to be? Secondly, `360/processes`? **Whoa!** Are your truly spawning 360+ processes all at once? Good luck with that. If you spawn fewer than 360 processes, `360/processes` is zero, and nothing is done. *What is it that you are trying to do?*

Comment: Processes is between 1 and 8. Yeah, the child processes are not supposed to fork each other, how do I keep that from happening?

Comment: @David Hammen: I should clarify that this is just a snippet of the code, matches is set earlier and should be between 10 and 10000. I'm spawning less than 360 processes, if I spawn 4 processes for example 360/processes would be 90. I have 360 tasks to complete and I'm trying to divide them evenly between the processes.

Comment: @WhozCraig no, each child process calls exit(0).

Comment: @immibis I see it now.. good call. that loop scared the hell out of me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
for(int v = p * (360/processes); p < (360/processes) * (p + 1); p++)
```

`p++` should be `v++`. `p <` should be `v <`.

Also, this won't process the last few elements, if 360 is not divisible by `processes`. Try this instead:

```
for(int v = (p * 360) / processes; v < ((p + 1) * 360) / processes; v++)
```

Also, because you wait for each process as soon as you start it, you're only running one process at a time, and you won't get any more speed by running processes in parallel.

Comment: +1 nice eagle eye. I'm not sure the `waitpid` should be in this for-loop as well (which I now see you just caught as well), as it seems the parent waiting for each child it just spawned is no better than serializing. Regardless, nice catch.

Comment: Oh thanks a lot that was pretty silly, I psyched myself out with all the forking stuff and was so sure that was the problem. Yeah that's a good point about the processes being divisible, my teacher was being nice and specified that processes would be 1, 2, 4, 6, and 8, I think exactly for that reason. Your way is definitely better though, I'll remember that trick in the future.

Comment: @user1023465 pay attention to that last paragraph. Move the `waitpid` logic to its own loop outside this one. Its a separate issue that is deserving of its own up vote, and if I could uptick this again I would. really a good answer.

Comment: Oh that makes a lot of sense, I see what you're saying yeah thanks for pointing that out